# Unable to correctly order and limit subnodes; WITH + OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets say i have following node relations:

`(:User)-[:MEMBER]->(:Room)<-[:HAS]-(:Photo)`

Also `:User` can be `(:User)-[:FRIEND]-(:User)` to other `:User`

`:Room` may have photos or may not.

What i'am trying to achieve - get 5 `:Room`'s sorted by `.creationdate`, get 4 `:Photo`'s for each of those rooms and sort them by `.date` (if there is any photos), and also get 5 friends, that are members of this room, without any sorting. I'm attempting to do this in one query, but i have almost gave up, maybe there is no way to do that and i need to make this as separate db requests?

So far query that looked for me as logically correct does not work - for example it gives back only 4 `:Photo`'s total and some of them without any connections to other nodes.

Query:

```
MATCH (u:User {id:'E17YfQyRgl'})-[:MEMBER]-(r:Room)
WITH r ORDER BY r.creationdate LIMIT 5 
OPTIONAL MATCH r-[:HAS]-(ph:Photo) 
WITH ph ORDER BY ph.date LIMIT 4 
OPTIONAL MATCH r-[:MEMBER]-(fr:User)-[:FRIEND]-(u:User {id:'E17YfQyRgl'})
return r,COLLECT(ph),COLLECT(fr)[..5]
```

As you can see i'm using inconsistent mashup of COLLECT, LIMIT and ORDER BY... but i'm just lost now, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you leave an identifier behind by leaving it out of a `WITH` clause, it becomes unbound. You think you are using an identifier but you are actually matching on all nodes at that point.

In particular,

```
WITH ph ORDER BY ph.date LIMIT 4 
OPTIONAL MATCH r-[:MEMBER]-(fr:User)-[:FRIEND]-(u:User {id:'E17YfQyRgl'})
```

Your `r` is no longer bound to anything. It wasn't included in the previous `WITH` clause; you only carried over `ph`. You're optionally matching on all nodes. Try something like this:

```
MATCH (:User {id:'E17YfQyRgl'})-[:MEMBER]-(r:Room)
WITH r ORDER BY r.creationdate LIMIT 5 
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:HAS]-(ph:Photo) 
WITH r, ph ORDER BY ph.date
WITH r, COLLECT(ph)[..5] AS photos
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:MEMBER]-(fr:User)-[:FRIEND]-(:User {id:'E17YfQyRgl'})
RETURN r, photos, COLLECT(fr)[..5]
```

Comment: Oh i see, i thought about it, as i recall i was trying something like this, isn't `WITH r, ph ORDER BY ph.date` going to reorder my r from previous r.creationdate to the order of ph.date in relations with r? Anyway i will surely try fiddle with it tomorrow, thx, i'll post back after i'll get some sleep =)

Comment: Yes. You can change it to `WITH r, ph ORDER by r.creationdate, ph.date`.

Comment: Sorry, Nicole, i was caught up in development and had no time to properly go back to this question, now i'm using query pretty similar to your answer and it seems that everthign is fine, thank you!